# Excel Won't Execute Horizontal Addition When Copying a Formula

Tags: worksheet-function

Never experienced this before. This is a very simple explanation of what happens. For example you have numbers in columns A, C, and E that are all different. In cell G1 you write a simple formula to add up the row numbers horizontally in cells A1, C1 and E1. It adds up correctly. Now you copy and past that formula in G2. When you look at the formula in G2 it shows =A2+C2+E2. But the result is the summation from G1. When you copy and past that formula to G3 you see in the G3 cell =A3+C3+E3 but the result is again from G1. I'm sure it is so simple that I'm missing something. But again I'm perplexed as I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Excel isn't calculating the value in the cells.

Have you got Calculations turned off or set to manual? The easiest way to check is to press F9 and let Excel calculate.

If that resolves the issue you can turn calculcations back on by going to Formulas> Calculation Options> Automatic